# Сборка exe из qt-проекта

Tags: qt, развертывание, release-management

Наверняка вопрос поднимался уже не раз. Я впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой и не нашел решения на форумах. В общем проблема в следующем: при попытке развернуть приложение qt я таскаю нужные библиотеки в директорию и обычно все было нормально. Сейчас словил ошибку: точка входа не найдена в DLL *и далее путь к моему экзешнику*. Путем интенсивного гугления выяснил, что проблема в библиотеках, мол не с той версии таскаю. Но собирал и руками и windeployqt,  и даже переустановил qt ,ничего не помогает. Нужна ваша помощь

P.S. Библиотеки Qt5Core, Qt5Gui, Qt5Widget из папки компилятора, которым собираю экзешник , другие либы двумя уровнями выше, из папки моей версии Qt

Comment: Я так понимаю, это происходит не на той машине, на которой оно собиралось? Имя DLL указано, или только путь к вашему EXE? Разрядность системы, где это происходит какая?

Comment: В том и дело что собираю на машине где и писал все. Указан полный путь к exe, и большими буквами DLL без конкретного указания библиотеки. Разрядность системы х64, собираю все в 32

Comment: Так ошибка при сборке или при запуске собранного приложения?

Comment: Ошибка при попытке запуска экзешника, во время сборки все отлично, обидно вот что не могу развернуть приложение на 5к строк

Comment: Если используется Qt с MSVC, можно попробовать обновить visual c redist

Comment: @BeardedBeaver не, mingw. Подумал что проблема в том что этап cmake выполняет кодблоксовский сборщик (фиг его знает почему он там вообще вылез). Поменял на родной,  все равно не работает

Comment: В результате кучи преобразований - от изменения настроек проекта до попытки статической линковки кьюта ловлю всего одну ошибку - не найдена точка входа в процедуру _cxa_throw_bad_array_new_lenght в библиотеке Qt5Core.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена добавлением остальных библиотек , после добавления libstdc++-6.dll ругаться перестал на потерянную точку входа в Qt5Core.dll